# Custom date range for report of upcoming changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, switch-statement

Relatively new to javascript, most self learning done through trial and error and internet searches.  Have an issue with code where I could use some expert guidance.

I need to show all changes with a planned start date occurring within our change week, which begins Friday at 00:00:01 and ends the following Thursday at 23:59:59.  The report would show all changes with a planned start date within that time period.

I was able to find the following script includes, modified slightly for my specific requirements.  When the script is called in reporting, I do not receive any results even though there is data that meets my criteria.

I believe my issue is with the array or loop, but am unable to resolve.

I have included only a portion of the script where I believe the issue resides, but can provide full code if helpful.

//Partial Code

```
    var ChangesPlannedCustom = Class.create();
    ChangesPlannedCustom.prototype = {
    initialize: function() {
    },

    testChangeWeek:function(){
    //Gets all current dates within current week and push into 'result'
    var current = new Date();
    var gdt1 = new GlideDateTime(current);
    var dateToday = gdt1.getLocalDate();
    var sunday = new Date(current.setDate(current.getDate() - current.getDay()));
    var b = gdt1.getLocalDate();
    var result = [b];

    while (sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() + 1) && sunday.getDay() !== 0) {

    var curr = new Date(sunday);
    var gdt = new GlideDateTime(curr);
    var c = gdt.getLocalDate();
    result.push(c);
}
    //Assigns dates with numbers.  Days contain respective dates.
    //SundayN = 0, MondayN = 1, TuesdayN = 2, WednesdayN = 3, ThursdayN = 4, FridayN = 5, SaturdayN = 6
var sunday1, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday; //sunday1 because sunday is already used above
var sundayN, mondayN, tuesdayN, wednesdayN, thursdayN, fridayN, saturdayN;
var today = dateToday;

var i = [];
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            sunday1 = result[i];
            sundayN = i;
            break;

        case 1:
            monday = result[i];
            mondayN = i;
            break;

        case 2:
            tuesday = result[i];
            tuesday = i;
            break;

        case 3:
            wednesday = result[i];
            wednesday = i;
            break;

        case 4:
            thursday = result[i];
            thursday = i;
            break;

        case 5:
            friday = result[i];
            friday = i;
            break;

        case 6:
            saturday = result[i];
            saturday = i;
            break;
        default: statement(s);
            break;
            }
}
var todayN = '';
    var q;
for (q = 0; q < result.length; q++) {
    if (result[q].toString() == today.toString()) {
        todayN = q;

    }
}
```

//code continues - not shown

I expect to receive a list of change numbers that have a planned start date within my specific date range.  Currently, when executing the code in reporting, I receive no results.

Appreciate any assistance provided.